# como mostrar el loop del Foreach de Laravel con letras

Tags: php, laravel

El loop muestra las iteraciones del foreach, pero las muestra con numero,
es posible que sean letras y no numeros:

ejemplo:

```
@foreach($listadeitems as $item)
 {{$loop->index}}
@endforeach
```

el resultado de ese foreach va hacer un listado numérico según el numero de items = 0,1,2,3,4...n

lo que quisiera hacer es que se muestre algo así: A,B,C,D...

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma faćil de hacerlo sería usando tu propio iterador, comenzando desde la 'A':

```php
$letras_iterator = 'A';
```

Algo así:

```php
@php
    $collection = collect([
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ', 'Item ',
    ]);
    $letras_iterator = 'A';
@endphp
<ul>
@foreach($collection as $item)
    <li>
        {{$letras_iterator++}} |
        {{$item}} |
        {{$loop->index}}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

De esa forma comenzará desde la 'A' otra vez, concatenando el caracter al que ya había cuando haya mas items que letras de la A a la Z (que como notarás, son solo 26).

```html
<ul>
<li>
    A |
    Item  |
    0
</li>
<li>
    B |
    Item  |
    1
</li>
<li>
    C |
    Item  |
    2
</li>
...
<li>
    Z |
    Item  |
    25
</li>
<li>
    AA |
    Item  |
    26
</li>
<li>
    AB |
    Item  |
    27
</li>
<li>
    AC |
    Item  |
    28
</li>
...
<li>
    AZ |
    Item  |
    51
</li>
<li>
    BA |
    Item  |
    52
</li>
<li>
    BB |
    Item  |
    53
</li>
<li>
    BC |
    Item  |
    54
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda!